# Efficient way to regex multiple linefeeds

Tags: java, regex, perl

I am searching for double-spaces or more on multi-gigabyte files.  I would like the best performance possible on searching (regex'ing?) for multiple line feeds (newlines).  Is there anything faster than "\n{2,}"?  I am using both Java and/or Perl and assuming Unix-like.  Also, I am assuming both platforms are embedded systems (i.e. no 3rd party libraries).

EDIT: I am trying to capture the data between the multi-linefeeds.  Currently using the Java Scanner class to capture the data.

Comment: Might be helpful if you explained what your actual goal is. For example, if you aren't looking to replace or capture the multiple line feeds, it would be slightly more efficient to just use `\n{2}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Added a slight edit that should hopefully add additional clarity.

Comment: You appear to be looking for performance, in which case I suggest that using regex is not the answer. Assuming a Java implementation I would recommend you simply scan the byte stream and buffer the bytes until two consecutive bytes are '\n', and then convert the buffer to whatever format you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can set the $/ variable to "\n\n", and then just read lines from the file. each "line" will be all the text between two new lines.

```
open my $fh, "<", "big_file.txt" or die "um, where did it go?";
local $/ = "\n\n";
while (my $rec = <$fh>) {
   .. process $rec
}
```